# PostgreSql Update RAISE_NOTICE runs before UPDATE

Tags: postgresql

I have a procedure which generates a checksum and add the same to a string passed to it. I noticed that RAISE_NOTICE runs more than the update statement. Any idea why it is so?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE public.validatefarmerid() LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

AS $BODY$

DECLARE
final_id        CHAR VARYING;
Vid_generated   CHAR VARYING;
Sno             BigInt;
T               BIGINT=1000001;
PK_Code int;
checksum_char char(1);

DECLARE 
C1 CURSOR
FOR SELECT SrNo,id_generated  FROM  GeneratedFarmerID WHERE FarmerID IS NULL and 
COALESCE(AssignedToState,0)=0;

BEGIN   
WHILE T<5000000 LOOP
INSERT INTO GeneratedFarmerID(ID_GENERATED) VALUES(CEILING(random()*100000000000));
T:=T+1;
END LOOP;

FOR C2 IN C1 LOOP

Sno:=c2.SRno;
Vid_generated:=CAST(c2.id_generated AS VARCHAR);
PK_Code=SP_Varoff(CAST(Vid_generated AS BIGINT));
checksum_char:=cast(PK_Code as char(1)); --checksum using verhoeff algorithm.       
final_id:=CAST(Vid_generated AS VARCHAR)||checksum_char; 
update GeneratedFarmerID set farmerid=final_id where Srno=Sno;   
RAISE NOTICE 'Final ID:%',final_id;
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: How did you come to the conclusion that the Raise Notice tuns more than the Update? They are each run once per iteration.

Comment: The real question is: why are you using such an extremely inefficient cursor approach? This could be done with a single INSERT statement without any PL/pgSQL code